# How to get the numbers which can divide all values in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, division

I'm writing a function which would give the number(s) that can divide all the numbers in an array.

```
function scf(array){
  var newarray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (var num = 1000; num > 1; num--) {
      if (array[i] % num === 0) {
        newarray.push(num);
      }
    }
  }
  return newarray
}
scf([133, 147, 427, 266])
```

However, it gives me all the numbers that can divide each numbers:

```
[ 133, 19, 7, 147, 49, 21, 7, 3, 427, 61, 7, 266, 133, 38, 19, 14, 7, 2 ]
```

And I hoped it would give only the numbers which can divide all four numbers in the array (in that case it would be [7]).

Any help, please?

Comment: Nothing's wrong with it I guess. We have to agree that this site is for all levels of programmers, including newbies. As long as they showed their effort I think this is a valid question

Comment: You can find the ["greatest common divisor"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) for the list of numbers you have. The factors of the GCD is your desired output.

Comment: Naive solution: pick the minimum number from the array given. Iterate from 2 to the minimum number and check if it can divide all the numbers from the array or not

Comment: just a question, does no answer (not only in this question) helps you? please up/down vote as wanted and accept an answer. please have a look here, too: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner on coding so by now I do my best to figure by myself and ask when I really can't solve it and become desperate.
So tell you the truth, as I became desperate, I was really hoping for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier to generate the numbers from 2 to the minimum value in the array, then `filter` them with an `every` test:

```js
const scf = input => (
  Array.from(({ length: Math.min(...input) - 1 }), (_, i) => i + 2)
    .filter(testNum => (
      input.every(item => item % testNum === 0)
    ))
);
console.log(scf([133, 147, 427, 266]));
console.log(scf([6, 12, 18]));
```

Comment: I posted an answer similar to you. Sorry, we had same thoughts.Anyway , upvote for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` method in order to get the *numbers* which can *divide* all values in the `array`.

Also, use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in order to find the min value from your given array and use it as argument for `Array.from` function which *generates* all `2...min` values.

```js
function scf(arr){
  let min = Math.min(...arr);
  return Array.from(Array(min - 1)).map((_, k) => k + 2).filter(num => arr.every(item => item % num == 0));
}

console.log(scf([133, 147, 427, 266]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function scf(array){
          var newarray = [];
          for (var num = 1000; num > 1; num--) {
            var count = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
              if (array[i] % num === 0) {
              {
                  count = count + 1;
              }
            }
            if(count==array.length)
                newarray.push(num);
          }
          return newarray;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the sprit of the function, but take only one value to get the divisors. Later reduce the arrays by checking common values.

```js
function scf(value) {
    var result = [],
        num;
    for (num = Math.floor(value / 2); num > 1; num--) {
        if (value % num === 0) {
            result.push(num);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(
    [133, 147, 427, 266]
        .map(scf)
        .reduce((a, b) => a.filter(v => b.includes(v)))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take GCD of all the number in your array, that will give you the no. which will divide every no in your array.

Moreover, the time complexity to find gcd of two number is logarithmic so overall complexity will be O(nlog(n)) where n is the no of elements in your array.Also,

> gcd (a,b,c) = gcd(a,gcd(b,c))